# $M(t) = 50e^{-0.02t}$ for A $N(t) = 75e^{-0.01t}+10$ for B for $t$ minutes . How long until $M(t)=N(t)/2$?

Tags: calculus

> There are two cups, A and B. They both contain a certain amount of
>   sugar that is dissolving.
>
> The mass of the amount of sugar that hasn't dissolved yet is given by
>   $$M(t) = 50e^{-0.02t}$$
>
> for cup A and by $$N(t) = 75e^{-0.01t}+10$$
>
> for cup B.
>
> Determine how long after the dissolution starts it will take for the
>   mass of the remaining amount of sugar in cup A to be half of the mass
>   of the remaining amount of sugar in cup B.

I did:

$$50\cdot e^{-.02t} = \frac{75e^{-.01t}+10}{2} \Leftrightarrow 100e^{-.02t} = 75e^{-.01t}+10 \Leftrightarrow \\ 
\frac{100}{75} = \frac{e^{-.01t}+10}{e^{-.02t}} \Leftrightarrow \frac{4}{3} = \frac{e^{-.01t}+10}{(e^{-.01})^{2t}} \Leftrightarrow \frac{4}{3} =(e^{-.01t})^{-1} + \frac{10}{e^{-.01}} \Leftrightarrow \frac{4}{3} = \frac{10}{e^{-.01t}}  + \frac{1}{e^{-.01t}} \Leftrightarrow \frac{11}{e^{-.01t}} = \frac{4}{3} \Leftrightarrow e^{-.01t} = \frac{33}{4} \Leftrightarrow t = \log_{e^{-.01}}{(\frac{33}{4})} \Leftrightarrow t \approx -211$$

But my book says the solution is 14 minutes.

What did I do wrong? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $x = e^{-0.01t}$, so that the problem becomes

$$
50 x^2 = (75 x + 10)/2
$$

whose solutions are

$$
x = \frac{15 \pm \sqrt{385}}{40}
$$

Takes only the positive, because $x>0$, and then you get

$$
e^{-0.01t} = x= 0.865535 \quad\Rightarrow\quad t = 14.4407
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$100e^{-.02t} = 75e^{-.01t}+10 \Leftrightarrow 
\frac{100}{75} = \frac{e^{-.01t}+10}{e^{-.02t}} $$ is not correct. It must say

$$100e^{-.02t} = 75e^{-.01t}+10 \Leftrightarrow 
\frac{100}{75} = \frac{e^{-.01t}+\frac{10}{\color{red}{75}}}{e^{-.02t}}. $$

Write $x=e^{-0.1t}.$ Note that $x^2=e^{-0.2t}.$ Thus your equation is $$100x^2-75x-10=0.$$ Or $$20x^2-15x+2=0.$$ Solve for $x$ and use that $t=-10\ln x.$